# When using Facebook-Fasttext to classify new text, why the data type of return is list?

Tags: python, fasttext

I'm trying to classify new text with Facebook-Fasttext module, the code is as follow:

```
#!usr/bin/python 2.7

import sys
import jieba
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

import fasttext
lines=[line.strip() for line in open('./corpus_seg2.txt', 'r')]
print(len(lines))
l_c=len(lines)
train_size=int(l_c*0.8)
text_size=l_c-train_size
train_set=lines[:train_size]
text_set =lines[l_c-train_size+1:]

with  open( "./train.txt", "w") as ftrain:
    for line in train_set:
      ftrain.write(line+'\n')
with  open( "./test.txt", "w") as ftext:
    for line in text_set:
      ftext.write(line+'\n')
ftrain.close()
ftext.close()

classifier = fasttext.supervised("./train.txt", 'model', label_prefix='__label__')

classifier = fasttext.load_model("./model.bin", label_prefix='__label__')

test_label=classifier.predict_proba('五五开 也 很 厉害 啊')

result = classifier.test("./test.txt")
print 'P@1:', result.precision
print 'R@1:', result.recall
print 'Number of examples:', result.nexamples
print test_label
```

The corpus_seg_2.txt is a file that has been segmented. The precision of model is 72%, the recall is 72%. 
Then, I used the model to predict a new text:'五五开 也 很 厉害 啊'. However, the test_lablel I got is confusing, I'm wondering why the result is this, how can I fix it?
[This picture will show you the result I got after running the code I provide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkmQG.png)

Answer (score 0):

@Arthur if you want the output to be a single value per sentence you need to change this: `test_label=classifier.predict_proba('五五开 也 很 厉害 啊')`
to 
`test_label=classifier.predict_proba(['五五开 也 很 厉害 啊'])`

That's because the predict function takes as input a text of type an array of string.